# Arithmetic on values with memory size units

Tags: shell, arithmetic

Let’s say I have a bunch of numbers representing quantities of memory, written in the form `86k` or `320m` or `1.7g` for instance. How can I compute their sum in command line, and get back a human-readable result?

Being able to compute subtractions would be nice too. The perfect tool would handle several sets of notations (such as `1g` / `1G` / `1GB` / `1Go` / `1GiB` / `1.7Gio`) and their meaning (binary or decimal multipliers).

I am looking for a pure calculator. These numbers are not necessarily the size of some files on my disk, so tools such as `find`, `stat` or `du` are not an option.

This is obviously easy to implement (with some hurdles regarding precision), but I would be damned if this didn’t exist already!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little self promotion: we wrote a library called [libbytesize](https://github.com/storaged-project/libbytesize) to do these calculations in C and Python and it also has a commandline tool called [bscalc](https://storageapis.wordpress.com/2019/08/04/bscalc-storage-size-calculator/)

```
$ bscalc "5 * (100 GiB + 80 MiB) + 2 * (300 GiB + 15 GiB + 800 MiB)"
1215425413120 B
1186938880.00 KiB
   1159120.00 MiB
      1131.95 GiB
         1.11 TiB
```

The library is packaged in most distributions, unfortunately the tool isn't. It's in Fedora in `libbytesize-tools` and SuSE in `bscalc` package, but not in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: In Archlinux the tool is included in the `libbytesize` package, so this is my favorite answer. In my opinion, it just lacks the ability to select the best prefix automatically w.r.t. the order of magnitude of the result (like `numfmt` does), and perhaps an option to switch the meaning of ambiguous units such as `K` to base 1000.

Comment: So you want to print only `1.11 TiB` in the example? I could add an option for that. I'm not sure about changing the meaning of `k` vs `K` that might be confusing, but I'll think about that. Feel free to report bugs and/or RFEs on GitHub if you find any issues.

Answer (score 7):

There is [Bcal](https://github.com/jarun/bcal).

```
$ bcal -m "(5kib+2mib)/2"
1051136 B
$ bcal -m "(5kb+2mb)/2"
1002500 B
```

The `-m` flag is for brief output. Removing it outputs verbosely with base 2 (KiB, MiB, GiB, TiB) and base 10 (kB, MB, GB, TB) results.

It does not understand `86k` or `320m` or `1.7g`, after all those are not proper byte units. In that case, you could use Sed to add the `b` after each letter and then pipe it to `bcal`:

```
$ cat file
1.7g+320m+86k
$ sed 's/[gmk]/&b/g' file | bcal -m
bcal> 1.7gb+320mb+86kb
2020086000 B
```

You can also use it in interactive mode.

Comment: After playing with it, I find that it does the trick but lacks flexibility. On input: indeed `k`, `m` and `g` are not proper units, but they are in wide use. [My ideal tool would accept any syntax in use but treat ambiguities conservatively, i.e. if units such as `k` or `kB` are used it would force the user to say on the command line whether they mean 1000 or 1024. (Another ambiguity is whether `b` means bit or byte.)] On output: it’s all or nothing, even though I can pipe `bcal -m` into `|numfmt --to=iec-i |tr -d ' '`… I prefer bscalc` on that regard.

Answer (score 6):

In `zsh`, you could define a math function like:

```
() {
  typeset -gA bsuffix
  local n=1 ni=1 s
  for s (k m g t p e) {
    (( n *= 1000 )); (( ni *= 1024 ))
    (( bsuffix[$s] = bsuffix[${s}ib] = bsuffix[${s}io] = ni ))
    (( bsuffix[${s}b] = bsuffix[${s}o] = n ))
  }
}
b() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  local s=${(M)1%(#i)(${(j:|:k)~bsuffix})}
  (( ${1%$s} * ${bsuffix[$s:l]-1} ))
}

functions -Ms b
```

Then you'd be able to use `b(1G)`, `b(1mB)` in any zsh arithmetic expression, like in `(( .... ))`, `$(( ... ))`, `$array[...]`, etc, or in `zcalc`:

```
$ <<< $((b(86k) + b(320mb) + b(1.7gio)))
2145449164.8

$ autoload zcalc
$ zcalc
1> b(86k) + b(320mb) + b(1.7gio)
2.14545e+09
2> :sci 15
2145449164.8

$ echo $(( b(infeo) ))
Inf
```

(note that we make no difference between `b` and `B` (or `o` / `O`), the match it case insensitive. It's not interpreted as *bit* vs *byte*).

Another approach could be to have the `b()` function take the whole expression as argument, and replace all the suffixes with `* $bsuffix[<suffix>]`

```
b() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  local s=${(M)1%(#i)(${(j:|:k)~bsuffix})}
  (( ${1//(#bi)([0-9.][[:blank:]]#)(${(j:|:k)~bsuffix})/$match[1] * $bsuffix[$match[2]:l] } ))
}
```

And then:

```
$ echo $(( b(1m + 1Mb) ))
2048576
```

There's the problem of `e`/`E` (*exa*) though which puts a spanner in the works in that `1e-3GB` would not be interpreted as `0.001 * 1000000000` but as `1 * 1152921504606846976 - 3 * 1000000000`.

In any shell with support for floating point arithmetic (ksh93, zsh, yash), you could always define:

```
  K=1024  M=$((K * K))  G=$((M * K))  T=$((G * K))  P=$((T * K))  E=$((P * K))
KiB=$K  MiB=$M        GiB=$G        TiB=$T        PiB=$P        EiB=$E
 KB=1000 MB=$((KB*KB)) GB=$((MB*KB)) TB=$((GB*KB)) PB=$((TB*KB)) EB=$((PB*KB))
```

Or to golf it:

```
K=1024 EiB=$((E=K*(P=PiB=K*(T=TiB=K*(G=GiB=K*(M=MiB=K*K))))))
KB=1000 EB=$((EB=KB*(PB=KB*(TB=KB*(GB=KB*(MB=KB*KB))))))
```

And write `$(( 1.1*GB + 5*K ))`

to add the suffixes on output, you could use GNU `numfmt`:

```
$ human() numfmt --field=- --to=iec --suffix=iB
$ echo $(( b(1m + 1Mb) )) | human
2.0MiB
```

Comment: I don’t use zsh, but this is a nice trick! If i read correctly the `:l` in `${bsuffix[$s:l]-1}` (and the `%(#i)` on the line before, I guess?), it even supports case variations. What does the `-1` do, however?

Comment: @Maëlan, `${var-default}` is a standard Bourne shell (from the 70s!) operator, to expand to `default` if `$var` is unset, here applied to the associative array expansion with `1` as the *default*. `$var:l` (or `${(L)var}`) converts to lowercase, `(#i)` is an `extendedglob` operator to enable case-insensitive match (similar to perl's `(?i)` regexp operator. See how `zsh` used the same trick using `#` (equivalent to regex `*`) after `(` which otherwise would have been invalid, like `?` is invalid otherwise after `(` in regexps to introduce a new operator without breaking backward compatibility).

Answer (score 4):

[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) (it's [one of the shells for *nix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7) for those of you who are wondering) has built-in ["SI" suffixes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57477641/995714) for [numeric literals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7) so you can use them directly

```powershell
PS /home> $f = 5 * (100GB + 80MB) + 2 * (300GB + 15GB + 800MB)
PS /home> $f
1215425413120
PS /home> "In MB: " + $f/1MB
In MB: 1159120
PS /home> "In GB: "; $f/1GB
In GB:
1131.953125
PS /home> "In TB: {0}" -f ($f/1TB)
In TB: 1.10542297363281
```

Those are binary prefixes and not decimal prefixes so if you want decimal units just multiply by `1eX` to get the desired value

```powershell
PS /home> 1KB; 1MB; 1GB; 1TB; 1PB
1024
1048576
1073741824
1099511627776
1125899906842624
PS /home> $K = 1e3; $M = 1e6; $G = 1e9
PS /home> 1*$G
1000000000
PS /home> 5 * (100*$G + 80*$M) + 2 * (300*$G + 15*$G + 800*$M)
1132000000000
```

You can store those constants in the [profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7) (similar to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in bash) to reuse them every time you open PowerShell

PowerShell is actually much more powerful than that. It runs on the .NET framework so it can do anything .NET can do: bigint math, decimal math, bitwise operations, trigonometry, date-time calculations...

---

Since the OP wants a *pure calculator*, I'll show some more examples on how PowerShell can be used for that purpose. The math functions above are mainly from the [.NET Math class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netcore-3.1) and [Numerics namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netcore-3.1). You'll put class .NET types inside `[]`, like `[math]` or `[system.math]` for the `Math` class (PowerShell is case-insensitive). Here are some other things that may be useful to programmers:

- Bitwise operations (bitwise operators begin with `-b` except shift operators)

  ```powershell
  [uint64]::MaxValue/3 + (-bnot 20) + (1L -shl 22) + (0x23 -band 0x34)
  ```
- [Big integer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1) math: `[bigint]::Pow([uint64]::MaxValue, 20)`
- Arbitrary integer and floating-point math expressions

  ```powershell
  1.56 + 0.23/[math]::Pow([math]::Sqrt([math]::Log(20) + [math]::Sin([math]::PI/3)), 4)
  ```
- Math on [decimal type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) (128-bit): `1.23d * 3.45d / 28`
- Math on [128-bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128) [integer types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128)
- Calculate file or object sizes: Use number suffixes `12.5GB + 5.8MB + 1392KB` for binary units and `12.5e9 + 5.8e6 + 1392e3` for decimal units (G = 1e9, M = 1e6, K = 1e3)
- Convert to/from base64: [`[Convert]::ToBase64String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8) and [`[Convert]::FromBase64String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Date/time](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1) manipulation. For example convert from raw Epoch values to datetime and vice versa

  ```powershell
    [datetime]::FromFileTime(0x01d15614cbaee92c)
    [datetime]::ParseExact("08-12-2012","dd-MM-yyyy", `
            [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
  ```
- String formatting and base conversion. Anything that [`String.Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1) in .NET supports will work. For more information read about the [formatting operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f). You can also do advanced string and regex manipulation. Some examples:

  ```powershell
    'somestring'.Substring(4) * 3 -replace 'ings', 'eet'
    '{0:X}' -f (0x12 + 34)
    [convert]::ToString(0x12 + 34, 16)
    'This is an emoji' + [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F60A)
  ```
- Direct [XML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7), [CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv), [JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1)... manipulation
- Call functions in *.SO (*.DLL in Windows) files directly
- GUI programming. Here's a small sample [clipboard history app](https://superuser.com/a/1440152/241386)

  [image: PowerShell sample]

For more information read

- [Doing Math with System.Math](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-static-classes-and-methods?view=powershell-7#doing-math-with-systemmath)
- [Using PowerShell to Work with Numbers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-windows-powershell-to-work-with-numbers/)
- [Playing with JSON and PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/playing-with-json-and-powershell/)
- [Time conversions in PowerShell (and .NET in general)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sergey_babkins_blog/time-conversions-in-powershell-and-net-in-general)
- [Understanding Numbers in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-numbers-in-powershell/)

or follow [Dr Scripto's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/author/the-scripting-guys/)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I compute their sum in command line, and get back a human-readable result?

Ksh supports floating-point math, so you can define the required constants in .kshrc and use them to do math

Then to get the *human-readable result* just use the built-in `printf` with `%#d` or `%#i`

> ```
> printf [ -v varname ] format [ arg ... ]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> - `#` The # flag, when used with the `%d` format without an output base, displays the output in powers of 1000 indicated by one of the following suffixes: `k M G T P E`, and when used with the `%i` format displays the output in powers of 1024 indicated by one of the following suffixes: `Ki Mi Gi Ti Pi Ei`.
>
> https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ksh/

For example

```
$ K=1024  M=$((K * K))  G=$((M * K))  T=$((G * K))  P=$((T * K))  E=$((P * K))
$ KB=1000 MB=$((KB*KB)) GB=$((MB*KB)) TB=$((GB*KB)) PB=$((TB*KB)) EB=$((PB*KB))

$ printf "%#i\n" $((12e+12 + 1.2e+9 + 12e+6))
11Ti
$ printf "%#d\n" $(((58*$K + 2*$M)/2))
1.1M
$ printf "%#d\n" $((5 * (100*$G + 80*$M) + 2 * (300*$G + 15*$G + 800*$M)))
1.2T
$ printf "%#d\n" $((1.7*$GB + 320*$MB + 86*$KB))
2.0G
```

Answer (score 0):

This is horrible, but in some cases one can get by with something like

```
cat my_columns.txt | cut -d " " -f 5-6 | sed "s/MB/*0.001/" | sed "s/GB//" | paste -sd+ - | bc
```